# How to use Bootstrap whilst maintaining semantic HTML markup?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, semantic-markup, separation-of-concerns

[Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) provides classes such as `text-left` ([Alignment classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)), `text-lowercase` ([Transformation classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-transformation)) etc, which is the same as defining inline-styles (not technically, but logically).

In an alternative methodology such as [`bem`](https://en.bem.info/method/), it imposes that classes should reflect 'physical' blocks and elements, and their modifier (or the state of the element, such as `active`, `current`), and any styles should be applied purely in the CSS.

The Bootstrap approach seems like a poor separation of concern between structure and presentation, and goes against this [W3C Tip for Webmasters](http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/goodclassnames).

This issue is echoed by many:

1. [Niko Sams - Why I don't like Twitter Bootstrap](http://www.nikosams.net/blog/5_why_i_don_t_like_twitter_bootstrap)
2. [Paradax - Bootstrap The good, the bad and the ugly](http://www.paradax.com/bootstrap-good-bad-ugly.html)
3. [bvision - Please stop embedding Bootstrap classes in your HTML!](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html)

**How does one use Bootstrap while still keeping the HTML markup semantic?**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Bootstrap provides [mixins](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-less) which you can use. So instead of adding classes like `col-xs-12` in the HTML, you'd use `@include make-xs-column(12)` inside the selector block for the element. To add a row, there's the `@mixin make-row`.

Referring to an answer by [Alexey Morashko](http://www.psd2html.com/experts/topic/how-to-create-a-bootstrap-grid-using-sass-mixins.html), instead of this unsemantic markup:

```
<div class="items-list row">
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="item-name">Product first</div>
        <div class="item-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="item-name">Product second</div>
        <div class="item-description">Ratione, ullam, reprehenderit aliquid saepe ab harum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <div class="item-name">Product third</div>
        <div class="item-description"> totam repudiandae velit eum accusantium veritatis.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can instead use:

#### HTML

```
<div class="items-list">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-name">Product first</div>
        <div class="item-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-name">Product second</div>
        <div class="item-description">Ratione, ullam, reprehenderit aliquid saepe ab harum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="item-name">Product third</div>
        <div class="item-description"> totam repudiandae velit eum accusantium veritatis.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.items-list {
    @include make-row();     
    .item 
        @include make-xs-column(12);
        @include make-sm-column(6);
        @include make-md-column(4);
    }
}
```

---

You can find more examples of Bootstrap mixins in the Sitepoint article - [5 Useful Sass Mixins in Bootstrap](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-useful-sass-mixins-bootstrap/).

Answer (score -1):

I found 3 css projects who does NOT require to use css classes. Just plain HTML5

https://github.com/picocss/pico

https://github.com/yegor256/tacit

https://github.com/Kimeiga/bahunya